# Calculate a new median for each row by id

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, grouping, median

I know this may be very simple but I can't solve it.

I have the following df:

**Input Data**

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,3,3,4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), value = c(956, 986, 995, 995, 986, 700, 600, 995, 956, 1000, 986))
```

**Desired Result**

```
df<-data.frame(id=c("1","2","3","3","3","4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), value = c("956", "986", "995", "995", "986", "700", "600", "995", "956", "1000", "986"), median = c("956", "986","995","995", "995", "700","650","700","828", "956", "971"))
```

This is, to calculate the median value for each row (taking into account the different ID's). In each row a new value will be added and then a new median should be calculated

**Output Data**

```
library(dplyr)
w = df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(median = median(value, na.rm =TRUE)) %>%
select (median)
df$median <- w[,2]


df<-data.frame(id=c("1","2","3","3","3","4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), value = c("956", "986", "995", "995", "986", "700", "600", "995", "956", "1000", "986"), median = c("956", "986","995","995", "995", "971","971","971","971", "971", "971"))
```

Comment: It sounds like you're after a rolling median; is that correct? Still, you're expected output does not quite make sense. For exampe take the first two rows for `id=4`. `median(c(700, 600))` will give you `650`, not `600`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: srry just fixed @MauritsEvers

Comment: @AM.Garcia Ok thanks. My solution below reproduces your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollapplyr` to calculate a rolling median:

```
library(tidyverse);
library(zoo);
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        median = rollapplyr(value, seq_along(value), median))
## A tibble: 11 x 3
## Groups:   id [4]
#      id value median
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1    1.  956.   956.
# 2    2.  986.   986.
# 3    3.  995.   995.
# 4    3.  995.   995.
# 5    3.  986.   995.
# 6    4.  700.   700.
# 7    4.  600.   650.
# 8    4.  995.   700.
# 9    4.  956.   828.
#10    4. 1000.   956.
#11    4.  986.   971.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1,2,3,3,3,4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    value = c(956, 986, 995, 995, 986, 700, 600, 995, 956, 1000, 986))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `cummedian` function in [cumstats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cumstats/cumstats.pdf) package which does the same.

```
library(cumstats)
ave(df$value, df$id, FUN = cummedian)

#[1] 956 986 995 995 995 700 650 700 828 956 971
```

which can also be translated into `dplyr` by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(median = cummedian(value))



#      id value median
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1.00   956    956
# 2  2.00   986    986
# 3  3.00   995    995
# 4  3.00   995    995
# 5  3.00   986    995
# 6  4.00   700    700
# 7  4.00   600    650
# 8  4.00   995    700
# 9  4.00   956    828
#10  4.00  1000    956
#11  4.00   986    971
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank you! :D